# Writing a typeclass with selection dependent on context bound

Tags: scala, shapeless

My initial code:

```
sealed trait Adder[L <: HList, U] extends DepFn2[L, Vector[U]]

object Adder {
  def apply[L <: HList, U: Ordering](implicit adder: Adder[L, U]): Aux[L, U, adder.Out] = adder

  type Aux[L <: HList, U, Out0] = Adder[L, U] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def found[T <: HList, U: Ordering]: Aux[Vector[U] :: T, U, Vector[U] :: T] =
    new Adder[Vector[U] :: T, U] {
      type Out = Vector[U] :: T
      def apply(l: Vector[U] :: T, collection: Vector[U]): Out = {
        (l.head ++ collection).sorted :: l.tail
      }
    }

  implicit def notFound[H, T <: HList, U: Ordering, OutT <: HList](implicit ut: Aux[T, U, OutT]): Aux[H :: T, U, H :: OutT] =
    new Adder[H :: T, U] {
      type Out = H :: OutT
      def apply(l: H :: T, collection: Vector[U]): Out = {
        val outT = ut(l.tail, collection)
        l.head :: outT
      }
    }

  implicit def empty[U: Ordering]: Aux[HNil, U, Vector[U] :: HNil] =
    new Adder[HNil, U] {
      type Out = Vector[U] :: HNil
      def apply(l: HNil, collection: Vector[U]): Out = collection :: HNil
    }
}
```

I found a bug where things that don't have the context bound
`Ordering`, the type is passed via `notFound` instead of `found`,
which is in hinsight not suprising. I tried to fix the bug by adding
another implicit which should trigger when there is no `Ordering`:

```
  implicit def foundNoOrdering[T <: HList, U]: Aux[Vector[U] :: T, U, Vector[U] :: T] =
    new Adder[Vector[U] :: T, U] {
      type Out = Vector[U] :: T
      def apply(l: Vector[U] :: T, collection: Vector[U]): Out = {
        l.head ++ collection :: l.tail
      }
    }
```

However, this results in an ambiguous implicit between the
`foundNoOrdering` and `found`. How can I have different code paths
dependent on if there is an `Ordering` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard trick is to reduce the priority by putting the implicit in an ancestor trait

```
object Adder extends LowPriorityAdderImplicits {
   implicit def found...
}

trait LowPriorityAdderImplicits {
  implicit def foundNoOrdering....
}
```

You will find a few of those in the standard library. LowPriorityImplicits seems to be customary in the name.

In the specification:

- SLS §7.2 Implicit parameters

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit
>   parameter’s type, a most specific one will be chosen using the rules
>   of static overloading resolution (§6.26.3)

- SLS §6.26.3 : The relevant bit is too long to cite in full, but you have something about

> A class or object C is derived from a class or object D if one of the
>   following holds:
>
> • C is a subclass of D, or
>
> • C is a companion object of a class derived from D, or
>
> • D is a companion object of a class from which C is derived.

and there being derived making it more specific and getting priority in resolution. I believe that one was made just for implicit.

Comment: Almost. When I don't add the found, I get:[error]  both method foundNoOrdering in trait LowPriorityAdderImplicits of type [T <: shapeless.HList, U]=> Adder.Aux[shapeless.::[Vector[U],T],U,shapeless.::[Vector[U],T]]
[error]  and method notFound in object Adder of type [H, T <: shapeless.HList, U, OutT <: shapeless.HList](implicit ut: Adder.Aux[T,U,OutT])Adder.Aux[shapeless.::[H,T],U,shapeless.::[H,OutT]]
[error]  match expected type Adder.Aux[shapeless.::[Vector[Foo],shapeless.HNil],Foo,Result]

Comment: I fixed that by moving the `foundNoOrdering` to the low implicit trait too.